# Как задать выравнивание полей эмбеда по вертикали вместо горизонтали в discord.py?

Tags: python, бот, discord.py

Я хочу сделать так, чтобы поля эмбеда выравнивались как на картинке 1:
[image: Картинка 1]

..А не как у меня:
[image: Картинка 2]

Подскажите, как так сделать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Тебе нужно добавить параметр `inline`.
Вот **пример кода**:

```
embed.add_field(name='Information', value='Описание', inline=False)
```

По дефолту параметр `inline` равен `True`, из-за этого происходит так, как ты показал на втором скрине.

Вот ссылка на документацию: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=embed#discord.Embed.add_field